# Receiving error while creating salesforce portal user in test class

Tags: user-admin

```
/** * An apex page controller that exposes the site login functionality */
@IsTest global with sharing class  DisplaySuppliersDetailsFormTest {    
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true) global static void testDisplaySuppliersDetailsForm () {
 //Insert The accounts
        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();

            for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++)
             {
                Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i, 
                                        BillingCity ='Kolkata',
                                        BillingCountry ='India',
                                        BillingPostalCode='560048',
                                        BillingState='Kolkata',
                                        Phone='8904145771',
                                        BillingStreet='Starlit Housing Complex');

                accts.add(a);
            }
    insert accts;
   //Insert The corresponding Contacts

    List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
    for (Integer j=0;j<10;j++) {
        Account acct = accts[j];            
        // For each account just inserted, add contacts
        for (Integer k=2*j;k<2*(j+1);k++) {
            cons.add(new Contact(firstname='Test'+k,
                                 lastname='Test'+k,
                                 AccountId=acct.Id));
        }
    }
    // Insert all contacts for all accounts
    insert cons;
    //Insert the test user
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='Testuserportal@atos.net', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='Testuserportal1989@atos.net');
        insert u;
         u.IsPortalEnabled = true;
         u.ContactId=cons[0].id;
         update u;

        //return u;
     //Insert the test user
   Financial_Statment__c FinancialStatmenttest= new Financial_Statment__c(Business_Company_Name__c=accts[0].id);
    insert FinancialStatmenttest;

     System.runAs(u) {
         DisplaySuppliersDetailsForm controller = new DisplaySuppliersDetailsForm ();
         //System.assertEquals(c !=NULL);

     }     
}
}
```

I am using the above code for creating the account associated contacts as well as a portal user .
I am getting the error as contact can be associated with only portal user.
Please help on this topic how can I enable the created contact as portal user / the user which is getting created can have contact assigned to it.

Answer (score 4):

The error is self explanatory. You can associate a Contact to a Portal User only. A Portal User will not have the System Administrator profile.

So replace this query

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
```

with

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Portal Profile'];
```

where Portal Profile is any Portal Profile associated with your Portal User.

Hope is helps.